# Sync CiviCRM Events with WordPress custom post type

Tags: civievent, wordpress

I want to Sync CiviCRM Events with WordPress custom post type. I.e. everytime I create/edit/delete CiviCRM Event the same happens with corresponding custom post type. This will bring new abilities (i.e. you'd have Featured image).
Is there a CiviCRM extension or WordPress plugin that provides this?

CiviCRM 4.7.7, WP 4.5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't put it on the WordPress repo yet, but there's [CiviCRM Event Organiser](https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-event-organiser). Repeat events only sync properly when the event is created in Event Organiser, but most of the other elements sync as you would expect. Event registration sync, however, is not yet completed.

Comment: sounds cool, what about this WP events plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/
Would it be straightforward to sync with it?

Comment: You can display CiviCRM Events with that, but there's no sync.